# Azure SDK 2.2 Installation issue

Tags: windows, azure, cloud

I have Visual Studio Ultimate 2013 Installed and I'm trying to install the Azure 2.2 SDK using the Web Platform Installer 4.6.

It seems to be stuck on: "Installing Windows Azure Emulator - 2.2 [2 out of 16]"

I tried uninstalling everything and then doing a manual installation, and the manual installation of the emulator is stuck on "Removing backup files".

Suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

Right click the file, run as administrator... seemed to work for me.

Comment: Yeah, had same issue for 2.7 (waiting for storage emulator for 3 hours). Downloaded installer and ran as Admin (instead of running from VS extensions) and seemed to be MUCH faster (<15 mins).